# C - Best inter-thread communication practice supporting both put and gets

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, ipc

Im trying to do an experiment where data and work is partitioned over the CPU cores on a specific machine. This is done by settings the CPU affinity and pinning one thread to each core. The data the thread stores is generated within the thread in an attempt to keep the data as close to the thread as possible (within the core cache). The data is of different types and each thread stores a different type of data. Now the main thread should be able to put and get data to each data container within each thread, but right here im not sure what to aim for.

The experiment is implemented in C.

**Assuming concurrent put and get requests to the different threads, which inter-thread communication technique would be best suited**? The idea is that i want as little data movement between cores as possible, therefore im trying to avoid using shared communication buffers/mutexes. I initially aimed for using sockets at each thread, but it is a bit too much work as this is not really the purpose of the experiment. Right now im considering using some type of queues, and i guess i would need to implement some input and output queues in order to handle both puts and gets. Therefore i came here to hopefully get some directions and tips.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try https://github.com/petercrona/StsQueue.

Comment: `Therefore i came here to hopefully get some directions and tips.` - Stack Overflow is badly suited for "suggestion" questions. Actually, "I want as little data movement between cores as possible" is quite unclear: assuming `put` stores data (from one thread) somewhere, and `get` extracts these data (on other thread), you already have "data movement" between threads and, consequently, between cores. Also, semantic of `get` and `put` in case of empty/full queue affects a lot on the effectiveness of one or another communication mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up @Tsyvarev the idea is that each thread will modify and work with the data and at less frequent times some other thread will put and get some data to this. So instead of having some data shared among the threads, where all threads are working with this data (creating greater data movement between cores), each thread will initialize the data storage and keep it close to itself. But i might be thinking incorrectly here. Also sorry if the questions seem vague, but that kind of why i came here in the first place